# Finding Mean Squared Error?

Tags: r, statistics, mse, mean-square-error

I have produced a linear data set and have used `lm()` to fit a model to that dataset. I am now trying to find the MSE using `mse()`

I know the formula for MSE but I'm trying to use this function. What would be the proper way to do so? I have looked at the documentation, but I'm either dumb or it's just worded for people who actually know what they're doing.

```
library(hydroGOF)

x.linear <- seq(0, 200, by=1) # x data
error.linear <- rnorm(n=length(x.linear), mean=0, sd=1) # Error (0, 1)
y.linear <- x.linear + error.linear  # y data

training.data <- data.frame(x.linear, y.linear)
training.model <- lm(training.data)
training.mse <- mse(training.model, training.data)

plot(training.data)
```

`mse()` needs two data frames. I'm not sure how to get a data frame out of `lm()`. Am I even on the right track to finding a proper MSE for my data?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I'm more-or-less asking where my predicted/simulated set of Y values can come from for the formula. In the `mse()` function, it requires an observed and simulated data frame. I need to know what to use for both those data frames.

Comment: I don't know why you'd use this weird function instead of `mean(training.model$residuals ^ 2)`

Comment: You can get the fitted values from the model, `training.model$fitted.values`, but they are a vector, not a data frame. So I suppose the alternative is `hydroGOF::mse(data.frame(training.model$fitted.values), training.data[["y.linear"]])`... also I'd **strongly** recommend specifying a formula when fitting a model. As you have it I think you're regressing `x` on `y`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I think you guys are right, I'll just do it the old fashioned way

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
mean((training.data - predict(training.model))^2)
#[1] 0.4467098
```

Comment: I was advised to use the `mse()` function but this is a way I'm more comfortable with. Thank you!

Comment: Special care needs to be taken when calculating MSE for multiple linear regression. The denominator to calculate MSE is `n - (p+1)`, where p is the number of predictors. Here, in case of simple linear regression, p = 1 so the denominator becomes n.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use below mentioned code which is very clean to get mean square error

```
install.packages("Metrics")
library(Metrics)
mse(actual, predicted)
```

The first data set on which is actual one : training.data 
The second argument is the one which you will predict like :

`pd <- predict(training.model , training.data)
 mse(training.data$,pd)`

Seems you have not done prediction yet so first predict the data based on your model and then calculate mse

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **residual** component from lm model output to find mse in this manner :

```
mse = mean(training.model$residuals^2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: if you come from another program (like **SAS**) 
they get the mean using the sum and the degrees of freedom of the residual. I recommend doing the same if you want a more accurate estimate of the error.

`mse = sum(training.model$residuals^2)/training.model$df.residual`

I found this while trying to figure out why  `mean(my_model$residuals^2)` was different in R than the **MSE** in **SAS**.